# No Resources are loaded when compiling manually with javac

Tags: java, javac

I want to manually compile Java-Code with javac. I'm using multiple Images loaded with `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("...")` If I run my Code in an IDE everything works fine. But when I'm trying to compile with javac no Resources are loaded. Is there a way to specify the Folder which contains all my Resources? I already tried `--add-module` but this didn't work either.
My command for compiling looks like the following: `javac -d ./out main/ai/*.java main/logic/*.java main/gui/*.java main/network/*.java && java -classpath ./out logic.Launcher`

Comment: Resources will only be loaded when you run the program with java.

Comment: Ok thanks. I explained it a bit wrong. When I then run the Program the Resources won't load.

Comment: You have to include your resources on the classpath. You're ide will usually copy the files over. javac does not manage that.

Comment: @matt So if I add -classpath path/to/my/res it should work?

Comment: @matt ok nice that worked :)

Comment: any reason not to use Gradle or Maven?

Comment: @Clashsoft this was for a exercise in university and my professor wanted to be able to compile and run with one command ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to just include the path to my Resource Folder in the classpath. I just had to add `-classpath path/to/my/res` So my working command looks like this: `javac -d ./out main/ai/*.java main/logic/*.java main/gui/*.java main/network/*.java && java -classpath ./out:./res logic.Launcher`